# To datasourceresult is taking very long time. Provided my class object is having around 250 variables

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

Below is my code snippet.

string query = $@" select name from inventory where id = @p1;

Var        data=mycontext.Database.SqlQuery(query,typeid);
Var returndata =data.ToDataSourceResult(request);

Here inventory is the view which contains around 262 columns and myclass is the corresponding c# class which contains the variable for view. I m getting data from db within seconds. But this ToDataSourceResult is taking very long time. Can anyone please help me on this. I cant make any changes to this view columns

Comment: Please post this on the Telerik forum.